# NodeJS one-shot script using MongoDB connection pooling - how to terminate?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm aware of the best practice of MongoDB connection pooling in NodeJS of the singleton DB connection type like this

```
var db = null;

var connection = function getDBConnection(callback) {
    if(db) { callback(null, db) } else { MongoClient.connect( .... )  }
}

module.exports = getDBConnection;
```

However, what I cannot get my head around at the moment is how to handle this in a one-shot script that, say, does some pre-initialization on the documents of a certain db collection:

```
getDBConnection(function (err, database) {
    var collection = database.collection("objects");

    var allObjectsArray = collection.find( /* ... */ 
    ).toArray(function (err, objects) {

        if(err != null) console.log(err);
        assert.equal(null, err);

        _.each(objects, function (item) {

            collection.update(
                { id:  item.id},
                { $set: { /* ... */ }},

                function (err, result) {
                    if(err != null) console.log(err);
                    assert.equal(null, err);
                }
            );

        });

        // database.close(); <-- this fails with "MongoError: Connection Closed By Application", thrown by the update callback

    });
    // database.close(); <-- this fails too, thrown by the toArray callback
});
```

If I call the script like that, it never terminates, due to the still open connection. If I close the connection at the bottom, it fails because of, well, a closed connection.

Considering that opening a new connection for every update is not really an option, what am I missing? Keeping the connection open may be fine for webapps, but for a one-shot script called from a shell script this really doesn't work out, does it?

Sorry if this question has arisen before, I've given it some research but have not quite been able to come up with a working answer for me...

Thanks!
Julian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a "pooled connection" there is code running to keep the connection alive and establish more connections in the pool if required under the driver connection. So much like various "server code" methods, event loop handlers have been invoked and the process does not exit at the end of your code until these are de-registered.

Therefore your two choices to call after all your code has executed are either:

1. Call [`db.close()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/1.4/api-generated/db.html#close) or in your code context specifically `database.close()` once all is done.
2. Call [`process.exit()`](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code) which is a generic call in node.js applications which will shut the whole process down and therefore stop any other current event loop code. This actually gives you an option to throw an error on exit if you want your code to be "shell integrated" somewhere and look for the exit status.

Or call both. `db.close()` will allow execution to the next line of code and whatever you put there will also run.

But you have to wait until everything is called, so you can cannot use synchronous loops with asynchronous code in the middle:

```js
async.each(objects,function(item,callback) {
    collection.update(
       { "_id": item._id },
       {
          // updates
       },
       callback
    );
},function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    database.close();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Neil! I'm aware of the `database.close()` mechanism, the only question is _where_ exactly to call it. I realized I should be more specific and edited the example code above to include the update statement, which is (apparently ?) also asynchronous.

Comment: @JulianRubisch Sorry but did not look at this properly to see the obvious. The basic point is to replace your underscore|lodash (whichever) `_each.` call with something like `async.each`. That at least has a callback mechanism that signifies the end of each iteration and of course the end of all iterations. Will try to edit with an example soon. But that is the general point.

Comment: Neil, thanks again. I will try that but I still dont quite see the point, since \_.each is synchronous and should complete once all updates are done, _unless_ update() itself is async. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @JulianRubisch `.update()` is asynchronous. Anything with a "callback" is asynchronous. So you need something to wait for those to complete before calling

Comment: Thanks... I was wrapped in callbacks here... guess that's why they call it _callback hell_